# Eclipse reports jars as missing but i have them in the project's maven dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

M2e downloaded my dependecies and they're shown in my maven dependencies folder yet they are still being reported as misssing in eclipse 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Check if maven dependencies are part of the project's classpath if not, then add it

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project and select `Maven` > `Update Project Configuration`.  Then select `Project` > `Clean...`.  If that doesn't work, post screenshots of your project's Maven classpath and what is missing.